# What should be the Type of input variable which is a Component - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am trying to create a reusable module. In that module, I want to feature to open different component using `MatDialog` . Lets call the component `StartActionComponent`. Normally, I can use:

```
export class StartActionComponent{

  async startbuttonClicked(e: SomeEvent){
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open( SomeModalComponent , {data: e});
  }
}
```

This works fine, but I want to dynamically inject a component , lets say `SomeModalComponent2`. I am trying to achieve that as below:

**DashboardModule**

```
export const START_COMPONENT = new InjectionToken<any>('START_COM');

export class DashboardModule {

  static forRoot(conf: {
    onStart: any
  }):ModuleWithProviders<DashboardModule>{
    return {
      ngModule: DashboardModule,
      providers: [
        {
          provide: START_COMPONENT, useValue: conf.onStart
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

in `StartActionComponent` component.

**StartActionComponent**

```
  constructor(
    @Inject(STOP_COMPONENT) startComponent: any) {}

  async startbuttonClicked(e: SomeEvent){
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open( this.startComponent , {data: e});
  }
```

and the  in `app.module.ts`

**AppModule**

```
import { SomeModalComponent2 } from 'some.modal2.component`;

@NgModule({
  import: [DashboardModule.forRoot(onStart: SomeModalComponent2)]
})
```

**I want to remove `any` and have a type for:**

```
static forRoot(conf: {onStart: any})
```

or

```
@Inject(STOP_COMPONENT) startComponent: any) {}
```

I tried ComponentType but no luck

Comment: May I ask, what value does having a module and component to pop the mat dialog have over directly referencing the mat dialog in the other modules? What problem is this solving for you? Could having a singleton service that pops the mat dialog work in place of this?

Answer (score 0):

I think I ran across a similair case whereas I wanted my dynamic components typed. So I made a new file called MyDynamicComponent.ts and it looked like this:

```
export type MyDynamicComponent = GridComponent | GridControlComponent | FeatureComponent | FeatureControlComponent;
```

In your case I believe it would be something like:

```
export type StartComponentType = SomeModalComponent | SomeModalComponent2;
```

I hope I understood your question correctly,

Comment: Naah, this one will restrict component of specific types. I am ok with any argument which is basically a component. I have also created my apps as lib , so this will create some circular dependency

Answer (score 0):

so far I always used `import { Type } from '@angular/core';`

To quote the documentation

> @description
> Represents a type that a Component or other object is an instance of
> An example of a `Type` is `MyCustomComponent` class, which in JavaScript is represented by the `MyCustomComponent` constructor function.

> export declare const Type: FunctionConstructor;

As for the generic `<T>` param, in your case you want to use `any`. Then it will force you to provide a component of any type, but still a component - a number/bool/string/etc. input would be invalid

Alternative: I think `ComponentType` from `import { ComponentType } from '@angular/cdk/portal/portal';`. But requires you to install the cdk package and the interfaces look exactly the same (if you ignore the extend)

```js
export interface ComponentType<T> {
    new (...args: any[]): T;
}

// vs.

export declare interface Type<T> extends Function {
    new (...args: any[]): T;
}
```

Comment: `ComponentType` needs a type `<T>`. what should be the generics here ?

Comment: if you only want to allow certain components you can provide those ComponentType<MyComponent | MyOtherComponent> now you can only provide either one of those. If you want to allow all just use any/unknown

Comment: @NicolasGehlert as he mention in the original question, he wants to get rid of the `any`

Comment: there's a fundamental difference between any and ComponentType<any>. In the first case you can provide even numbers, strings, bool whatever. The latter however forces you to provide a component instance. And if you don't want to further specify which are allowed (for example because you build a library) any is the way to go

Comment: now that, should be part of the answer you provided